dynamic hedging Formula
novice member here. not sure if im in the right forum, if not please let me know.
I am trying to create a hedging EA for my specific needs, but cant figure out the right formula, so i was wondering if anybody could help.
I want to inversely copy trade between accounts so that if I gain/lose x Percent in Account1, I would lose/gain a specific amount in absolute dollars in Account2.
for example:
I want to gain/lose 400USD when I lose/gain 10% of my 5000USD account.
I initially thought it would be as easy as setting the lot size multiplier to 0.8, but that only works if the first position reaches the 10% threshold in one trade. if it takes several trades and goes back and forth, the hedge (especially with different slippages) goes off by quite a significant margin (I've experienced ~40%).
so i figured I need to do dynamic hedging and re-calculate each time after a position is closed what size to take.... but cant figure out the formula.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
KR,
